# getting pppd "must be root" after setting whole fs with chmod 777

Tags: permissions, pppd

I have a process called `network_manager` which at some point runs a command `/usr/sbin/pppd`. everything works fine.

But then, some files becomes unreadable on the file system and I use `sudo chmod -R 777 rootfs` in order to get access right. Once I run this command, the `network_manager` can no longer run `/usr/sbin/pppd`, I get an error :

`/usr/sbin/pppd: must be root to run /usr/sbin/pppd, since it is not setuid-root`

I dont get it, running `chmod 777` isn't changing the owner of `pppd` so why it's no longer working ?

it worked by setting

```
chown root /usr/sbin/pppd 
chmod u+s /usr/sbin/pppd
```

but I don't understand why

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By running `chmod 777`, you removed the setuid bit on `pppd`. To restore it, you need to run

```
chmod 4755 /usr/sbin/pppd
```

Note that by running a recursive `chmod 777` in this manner, you’ve probably broken other permissions, and you’ve certainly made your system rather insecure.